# how to use sonarqube in android studio

Tags: maven, android-studio, sonarqube

I would like to use SonarQube to check my Android code. 
I installed the plugin of sonarqube the and also can access http://localhost:9000.
But when I click the "associated with sonar". The error is"Project is not associated to SonarQube
Only multi-module Maven projects are supported for now"

what can I do for my project?

Comment: Check out https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/integrating-and-understanding-sonarqube-in-android/ for detailed explanation on how to integrate and use sonarqube in android

Answer (score 0):

As a "first" version of the Intellij plugin it was decided to limit support to:
  - single module projects
  - multi-module Maven projects
Non Maven multi-module projects are not supported, but that's definitely a goal for next version:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-3401